# CoreData Batch Insert with Extra Keys (Cocoa error 1605.)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, batch-processing, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using `CoreData` to insert an array of dictionaries (`[[String: Any]]`) representing objects into a `PersistentStore`. When inserting the objects, I get the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1605.)`. The next line printed to the console is:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1605 "(null)" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=date, NSValidationErrorObject=Bot}
```

I am creating the array of dictionaries from a `JSON` object that has more keys than the corresponding `ManagedObject` in `CoreData`. Can I use `NSBatchInsertRequest` with keys that aren't in the corresponding `ManagedObject`?

Here is the code:

```
let batch: [[String: Any]] = getBatch()
let request = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: Bot.entity(), objects: batch)
let insertResult = try self?.managedObjectContext.execute(request) as? NSBatchInsertResult
let result = insertResult?.result as? Bool
print(result?.description ?? "")
```

Comment: Is `date` one of the keys in the json that doesn't correspond to a managed object property? I'm guessing so from the error message. Have you tried removing unneeded key/value pairs from the dictionary?

Comment: It was one of the keys not in the managed object. I ended up just implementing all of the possible keys as optional values in `CoreData` and that solved my issue but I'm still curious to know if I am required to do it this way or not. I assumed it would work like JSON decoding though.

Comment: If I were you I would remove all the key/value pairs that you don't need from the dictionaries before your batch insert. Don't add properties to your entity if you don't need them.

Comment: There are several init methods for NSBatchInsertRequest that takes a closure as an argument that is passed either a dictionary or a managed object, have you tried to use any of them? I have no personal experience with them but I looks like it could be useable here.

Answer (score 0):

Get entity description from persistentStoreCoordinator instead of `Bot.entity()`. I also experienced the same issue, and it was resolved by doing this. It seems to be a Core Data bug.

```swift
let botEntity: NSEntityDescription! = self?.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName["Bot"]

let batch: [[String: Any]] = getBatch()
let request = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: botEntity, objects: batch)
let insertResult = try self?.managedObjectContext.execute(request) as? NSBatchInsertResult
let result = insertResult?.result as? Bool
print(result?.description ?? "")
```

Also, `objects` (input of NSBatchInsertRequest) must not contain [transient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspropertydescription/1506766-transient) property.